# Collision on BorderBody in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I’m making game in school similar to Don’t touch the spikes and I would need an advice about collisions with the edges if screen in Swift. U gave set up borderBody a I need something to happen when it hits the side, even some print would be ok. The ball is reflecting, but I don’t know how to make some reaction on it. I need collision on right and left separately.

BordeBody:

```
let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    borderBody.friction = 0
    self.physicsBody = borderBody
```

Ball:

```
ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")
    ball.name = "ball"
    ball.size = CGSize(width: screenSize.width / 4, height: screenSize.height / 7)
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: 150, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.frame.height / 2)
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.ball
    ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.ground
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.ground
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    ball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    ball.zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(ball)
```

Collision struct:

```
struct PhysicsCatagory {
static let ball : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
static let ground : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
static let ground2 : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
static let obstacle : UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
}
```

Thanks

Comment: A minor point - start your PhysicsCategories bit-shifted by 0, not 1. UInt32 0x1 <<1 = 2 (you've shifted the bit 1 to the left), so the categorybitMask value of 1 won't get used. This won't be an issue until you get to 31 defined categoryBitMasks and want to add another 1.

Comment: So I do not understand this. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: physicsCategory is a UInt32 (i.e. 32 bits long).Only 1 bit should be set at a time, with a value of 0 meaning 'interacts with everything', so the int values you should be using are 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 etc which can be represented as a value of 0x1 shifted left by 0, 1, 2, 3, etc positions.
So your 'shifts' should start at 0 . You can go up to 0x1 << 31, so if you start with a shift of 1, then the value 1 (0x1<< 0 ) isn't used and you've wasted a category. The value 0 is just 0, not 0x1 shifted by any amount (well, it 0x1 >> 1 but that's not as clear as just 0).

Comment: I partly understand that, but just do not know how i do collision. I am a beginner, i need to school. Thanks for this advice

Comment: You will need to assign a physicsCategory to your borderbody. Then set the ball's contacttestBitMask to include the boderBody's categorybitMask. You will also have to set the phsicsWorld.contactDekletegate, set your game class as implementing  SKPhysicsContactDeletegate protocol and then implement the didBeginContact function.